# Hibernate - How to sort internal query lists (or List in List)?

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, sql-order-by

What is the best way to query an Object and return its list attributes in a sorted list?

Example:

Given the scenario below, what is the best way to do a Groups query, by bringing: the list of Items ordered by name and (for each item) the list of StateItem ordered by the Description of StateObject?

```
public class Group {

    // ...

    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
    private List<ItemGroup> itemList;

    // ...
}

public class ItemGroup {

    // ...

    @JoinColumn(name="ID_GROUP", referencedColumnName="ID_GROUP")
    @ManyToOne
    private Group group;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
    private List<StateItem> stateList;

    // ...
}

public class StateItem {

    // ...

    @JoinColumn(name="ID_ITEM", referencedColumnName="ID_ITEM")
    @ManyToOne
    private ItemGroup item;

    @JoinColumn(name="CD_STATE", referencedColumnName="CD_STATE")
    @ManyToOne
    private StateObject state;

    // ...

}

public class StateObject {

    // ...

    @Column(name="DE_STATE_OBJECT", length=255) 
    private String description;

    // ...
}
```

PS: I think I can't use @OrderBy because I have to sort by child attributes, as in the StateObject example. 
And the solution with @SortNatural or @SortComparator isn't performatic. 
Can I do that work using only HQL or Criteria?

Comment: Better to write `@NamedQuery` in parent class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.hibernate.annotations.@SortNatural` if `StateItem` implements comparable or you can use `org.hibernate.annotations.@SortComparator` and provide a comparator.

NOTE : This solution does in-memory sorting which is different than ordering (as provided by `@OrderBy`) which is applied during the SQL SELECT.

Comment: Yes. I think this works, but it's not a good solution for large lists because of performance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the [@SortComparator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/SortComparator.html) annotation which accepts a default value the class implementing `Comparator<T>`.

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@SortComparator(StateItemComparator.class)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
private List<StateItem> stateList
```

Its method should define the comparing strategy.

```
public class StateItemComparatorComparator implements Comparator<StateItem> {
    @Override
    public int compare(StateItem s1, StateItem s2) {
        return b1.getState().getDescription().compareTo(b2.getState().getDescription());
    }
}
```

Comment: @SortComparator only works for Set or Map, not for List. This is mentioned in the Javadoc and also in this issue: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9304