# @OrderBy Hibernate: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

So I have three entities. A `FormCollection` contains multiple `Form`. The `Form` is created from a template and thus has also a many-to-one relation to `FormTemplate`.

```java
@Table(name = "form_collection", schema = "public")
public class FormCollectionDO extends BaseAuditableDO {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "formCollection")
    @OrderBy("formTemplate.templateId") //throws error
    private List<FormDO> forms = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Table(name = "form", schema = "public")
public class FormDO extends BaseAuditableDO {

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "form_template_id")
    private FormTemplateDO formTemplate;
}

@Table(name = "form_template", schema = "public")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class FormTemplateDO extends BaseDO {

    @Column(name = "template_id", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Long templateId;
}
```

`@OrderBy("formTemplate.templateId")` throws an error:

> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "formtemplate"

`@OrderBy("formTemplate.id")` works fine. The id comes from the abstract class `BaseDO`. Why does it not work with any of the fields from the `FormTemplateDO` class?

Comment: form_template and formTemplate aren't the same, which one do you need?

Comment: For my understanding `form_template` is on DB level while `formTemplate` is on Java level. If I use `@OrderBy("form_template.template_id")` I get the same error.

Comment: I get auto-complete with `formTemplate.templateId` in IntelliJ. Also, since it works with `formTemplate.id`, I guess I need `fromTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure about this solution, What I am suspecting is this issue happens because the `formTemplate.templateId` isnt part of your query indeed.

I see you are using `@OneToMany` for defining the relationship, but in hibernate, the default FetchMode is `SELECT` which means your order by parameter isnt part of your query. To make this parameter part of your query, you will have to make a Join query.

Try this out -

```
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN) 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "formCollection")
@OrderBy("formTemplate.templateId") //throws error
private List<FormDO> forms = new ArrayList<>();
```

And propogate this join to further levels. It might solve your problem.

Comment: throws the same error for me

Answer (score 0):

When you want to order by a collection of entities by a nested attribute, you can not use `@OrderBy`, because the nested attribute is not part of your query. You can only use `@OrderBy` for of first level attribute OR a nested attribute IF it is a collection of `@Embeddable`.

So for this case, you have to use `@SortNatural` or `@SortComparator`.

- Similar issue : [Hibernate - How to sort internal query lists (or List in List)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496626/hibernate-how-to-sort-internal-query-lists-or-list-in-list)
- More about `@OrderBy` vs `@SortNatural`: [Sort vs OrderBy - performance impact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385480/sort-vs-orderby-performance-impact)